# why are the bytes in byte array reversed in C++

Tags: c++, byte, arrays, endianness

the code i am trying to understand overwrites a section of a game process memory (window.h, WriteProcessMemory) in order to modify a parameter in the game (for example, strength). the values would most likely be integers

the code attempts replacement with this function

```
WriteProcessMemory( GameHandle, (BYTE*)StrengthMemoryAddress, &StrengthValue, sizeof(StrengthValue), NULL);
```

where StrengthMemoryAddress is a pre-calculated dynamic address and StrengthValue is the following:

```
byte StrengthValue[] = { 0x39, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0 };
```

it replaces strength with 1337

my question is basically how the byte array works in this function. from google i know that the hex value of 1337 is 0x539.

how come you have to reverse it in the byte array? i see that he first puts 0x39 then 0x5, which i concluded probably combines to 0x539 in some reverse order. also, why do you need the extra 0x0 at the end - can't you just leave it out?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> from google i know that the hex value of 1337 is 0x539.

Or it is 0x00000539 which is same but written as a 4 byte integer. Now if you write this integer in little endian way in memory you would have to store it in following order (Least significant byte - 0x39 - goes first):

```
Memory Address   Values
1000             0x39  
1001             0x05
1002             0x00
1003             0x00
```

So that has to do with endianness. You may want to read more on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

You were expecting the `0x39` to be the highest byte (`Big Endian`), but you ended up on an architecture where it is the lowest byte (`Little Endian`).

Looking at an `int` logically as:

```
[ BYTE 0 ][ BYTE 1 ][ BYTE 2 ][ BYTE 3 ]
 * 256^3    *256^2    *256       *1
  MSB                            LSB
```

But that does not mean the architecture you are on maps a `char` array in that way.  In, fact it did the opposite.

```
value [what you expected]  [what you got]
       BIG ENDIAN           LITTLE ENDIAN
0x39      BYTE 0              BYTE 3
0x05      BYTE 1              BYTE 2
0x00      BYTE 2              BYTE 1
0x00      BYTE 3              BYTE 0
```

If you do not set all 4 bytes than the missing bytes are called `uninialized memory` and using it through the `int` you create is considered `undefined behavior`.  This will likely just leave an unexpected value in the missing byte (whatever happened to be there before), but the compiler is free to do whatever it wants, like removing code you thought would do something, leading to very unexpected behavior for you.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you're writing have to be in Little Endian format. I recommend you read up on [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

As for the extra 0 at the end: You have to overwrite the entirety of the byte-length of the int, or you'll risk leaving behind old values which would corrupt the value of the int you're writing.