# C++ int* and char* byte order swapped

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm trying to read and analyze a binary file. I was trying to convert integers into char arrays ( cut int into bytes ) and printig them as bitsets. I've noticed that the same data stored inside integer had reversed byte order than when stored as char, having the same number order inside of array, and the same bit order inside of byte. I would like to know why is that and eventually how to change that.

Example code showing the problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   unsigned int a[]={5,4,6};
   char *b=(char*)a;
   for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
   {
       cout<<bitset<32>(a[i])<<" ";
   }
   cout<<"\n";

   for(int i=0;i<12;++i)
   {
       cout<<bitset<8>(b[i])<<" ";
   }


}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000101 00000000000000000000000000000100 00000000000000000000000000000110
00000101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Great first question by the way. I suspect you'll find several duplicates if you search for "endian".  Since you didn't know the term to search for:  Completely Understandable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why are the bytes in byte array reversed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251746/why-are-the-bytes-in-byte-array-reversed-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

> I've noticed that the same data stored inside integer had reversed byte order than when stored as char

This implies that the file was stored with different byte endianness than what the CPU uses. In the example output, you can see that the CPU uses little-endian (least significant byte first). Given that the order was the opposite in the file, we can deduce that the file uses big-endian (most significant byte first). Big-endian is commonly used in data exchange formats.

> I would like to know why is that and eventualy how to change that.

POSIX has standard functions for converting big endian to native endianness (the `ntoh` family of functions). Standard C++ does not, but it is fairly straight forward to implement. However, there are some mistakes that are easy to make, so it will be safer to use an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mat briefly explained, you're running into something called "endianness".  There's "Big Endian", where the most significant bits are at the beginning?! (yes, it's a bit counter-intuitive), and "Little Endian", where the least significant bits are at the beginning.

> For example: Arabic numerals are big endian.  "1234" is "one-thousand two hundred thirty four", not "four thousand three hundred twenty one".  The most significant digits come first.

I'd be shocked to find that there aren't dozens of different open source functions handling this problem out there.

A quick google search turned up: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html

This is caused by different CPU architectures.  Some are big endian, some are little.  There's almost certainly a list at Mat's linked wikipedia page.  When they write out their bits to their own storage, they often write them "natively", in their own endian format.  This could be a big problem when a server talks to clients using a variety of cpu types (every web-server ever, most cross-platform networked games, etc.).  In those cases, the communication protocol must specify which endianness they're using and then the software must translate as needed.

#### Edit the edit:

"Endianness" should be called "startianness".  Counter intuitive names are bad.  "Principle of Least Surprise" good.

Ah well.

When it matters just use an existing library.  POSIX has a collection of not-terribly-standardized-names for functions that do the work.  There's the boost library I linked above.  I've used proprietary libraries on a couple projects.  I'm quite sure there are others out there as well, many open sourced.

Comment: Arabic numerals are big-endian. Little endian would be writing four thousand as 0004.

Comment: `0x01020304` is stored in memory as `01 02 03 04` for big-endian (most significant bits at the beginning), and `04 03 02 01` for little-endian (least significant bits at the beginning).  Motorola's 68000 series are big-endian, Intel's 80x86 series are little-endian.

Comment: I don't like the analogy to digits in decimal system. The difference when using different endianesses (is this the plural?) is that order of the bytes is turned around not the order of the bits. So `11110000 00111100` becomes `00111100 11110000` and not `00111100 00001111`.

Comment: Naming of endianness is confusing - big endian is **not** having the most significant at the end in memory, but at the beginning.